# How to switch base_uri with httparty

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am trying to pass a parameter to a `login` method and I want to switch the base uri based on that parameter.

Like so:

```
class Managementdb
  include HTTParty

  def self.login(game_name)
        case game_name
        when "game1"
            self.base_uri = "http://game1"
        when "game2"
            self.base_uri = "http://game2"
        when "game3"
            self.base_uri = "http://game3"
        end

    response = self.get("/login")

        if response.success?
      @authToken = response["authToken"]
    else
      # this just raises the net/http response that was raised
      raise response.response    
    end
  end

  ...
```

Base uri does not set when I call it from a method, how do I get that to work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In HTTParty, `base_uri` is a *class method* which sets an internal options hash. To dynamically change it from within your custom class method `login` you can just call it as a method (not assigning it as if it was a variable).

For example, changing your code above, this should set `base_uri` as you expect:

```
...
case game_name
  when "game1"
    # call it as a method
    self.base_uri "http://game1"
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you need to call a class method of a Mixin in your initialize() method, you need to call `YourClassName.mixin_class_method`.

Comment: In my `initialize` method I had to call `self.class.base_uri "http://example.com"` for it to work.

Comment: @hamstar but that will change the base_uri for all instances? so, all instances will behave like the last one, right ?

Comment: Remember to change `base_uri` back to whatever it originally was at the end of the method call if you want to use the instance again with the original value.

Answer (score 11):

I can’t comment yet, so here’s an extension to Estanislau Trepat’s answer.

To set the `base_uri` for **all your calls**, call the according class method:

```
self.base_uri "http://api.yourdomain.com"
```

If you want to have a way of sending **only a few calls to a different URI** and avoid state errors (forgetting to switch back to the original URI) you could use the following helper:

```rb
def self.for_uri(uri)
  current_uri = self.base_uri
  self.base_uri uri
  yield
  self.base_uri current_uri
end
```

With the above helper, you can make specific calls to other URIs like the following:

```rb
for_uri('https://api.anotheruri.com') do
  # your httparty calls to another URI
end
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot. However, it's important to not that this will return the `base_uri` as it's return value.  That will not help if you need to do something with the return value.  To improve this, `response = yield` and then have `response` as the last line to return the response value from the httparty call

Comment: I like this approach too, and used it... and then realized one more thing.  If your `yield` results in an exception, then your `base_uri` will get "stuck" with what should've been a temporary `base_uri`!   So using a `begin/rescue/ensure` block to make sure that your `self.base_uri` will be restored even in the case of an exception is a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not certain it was implemented when this question was first asked, but if you want to set or override `:base_uri` on a per-request or per-instance basis, HTTParty request methods (:get, :post, etc) [accept options](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods) to override class options.

So for OP's example, it could look something like this:

```
class Managementdb
  include HTTParty

  # If you wanted a default, class-level base_uri, set it here:
  base_uri "http://games"

  def self.login(game_name)
    base_uri =
      case game_name
      when "game1" then "http://game1"
      when "game2" then "http://game2"
      when "game3" then "http://game3"
      end

    # To override base_uri for an individual request, pass
    # it as an option:
    response = get "/login", base_uri: base_uri

    # ...
  end
end
```

Calling the class method dynamically, as suggested in some of the other answers, changes the base_uri for *all* requests, which is probably not what you want.  It's certainly not thread-safe.